# Python OS Module

Tags: python, shell, command-line

What I am trying to do in the OS Module in Python is to perform the 'logout' action that one would normally perform on the command line. I write:

```
os.system('logout')
```

BUT, when I do that, I get:

```
sh: line 0: logout: not login shell: use `exit'
```

So, I tried making it:

```
os.system('exit')
```

Which merely exits out of the python program, it does NOT perform the 'logout'.
How do I do this? Is it possible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Logout" is something that happens when a shell that is started as a "login shell" exits. No other program can do a `logout` command, because only the act of exiting the login shell does a logout.

Having said that, you might be able to find an appropriate login shell belonging to the current user, and kill it. Make sure you get the right one though, users can be logged in more than once and killing the wrong one would be annoying.

Answer (score 1):

logout is a shell command (i.e. part of bash or csh or whatever you use). It is not an executable of the system, just part of the scripting language.

Ask yourself what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw your question and noticed that you had accepted an answer that is incorrect.

What you want to do is initiate the shutdown cmd command. This is a very powerful command that will require you to have administrator access on the PC in question.

To log off the computer (but not force quit), use this command in python:

```
os.system("shutdown -l")
```

To shutdown the computer and close all programs, use this command:

```
os.system("shutdown -s -f")
```

To shutdown the computer, close all programs automatically and display a custom warning message for a set amount of time, use this command:

```
os.system("shutdown -s -f -t <time> -c <message>
```

*In the example above, replace  with the amount of time to earn the user for (in seconds). Replace  with a custom message to display during the warning period.*

Hopefully this will help you.